# What causes two identical instances to produce different result?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\pstVerb
{
    /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def
    /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def
}

\def\Atom{%
    \pstVerb{/Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def}% reset
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
    \multido{\ii=1+1}{3}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)}}%
    \expandafter\psrline\points}

\begin{document}    

% one instance
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\Atom
\end{pspicture}

% two instances
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\Atom
\Atom
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**One instance**

[image]

**Two instances**

[image]

### Question

Why does a single instance of `\Atom` produce correct result while 2 identical instances of `\Atom` produce wrong result?

### Real Scenario

I want to mimic the behavior of

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5) 
  \psset{linecolor=blue}
  \pstVerb{/Angles 0 def}
  \psStartPoint(0,0)
  \psVector[arrows=-](1,0)
  \multido{\i=1+1}{15}
  {% why is % needed here?
     \pstVerb{Angles 1 \i\space 1 sub sqrt atan add /Angles exch def}
     \psVector[arrows=-](!1 Angles PtoC)
     \psline(!cp.X cp.Y)
  }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with the following but it produces a wrong output.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstVerb
{
    /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def %
    /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\io=1+1}{15}{%
    \pstVerb{/Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def}% reset
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
    \multido{\ii=1+1}{\io}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)}}%
    \expandafter\psrline\points
    \psline(!CPx CPy)%
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you want the postscript code to do?  For example, I'm not quite clear on `CPx` or `CPy`, particularly with `/CPy` and `/CPx` in the middle of the binding.

Comment: @A.Ellett: See my update please.

Comment: I understand `CPx` and `CPy`, but what's `ED`?

Comment: @A.Ellett `ED` is defined as `exch def`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that you work in different Postscript dictionaries.

The "reset" part is done in one dictionary (I'm not sure, in which one), whereas the evaluation of the node content is done inside the `tx@Dict` dictionary.

Usually, when you call a Postscript operator or a variable, the interpreter first looks in the current dictionary, then in the parent dictionary and goes up the dictionary stack until it finds the first definition of the requested name. For the first call of `\Atom`, there is no `Angles` defined in `tx@Dict`, so the value of the parent dictionary is used (where `Angles` is defined as `0`). When `\Atom` is called for the second time, there is a `Angles` defined in `tx@Dict`, i.e. the last value of the first `\Atom` call.

To fix this, you must do the "reset" part inside the `tx@Dict` dictionary:

```
\pstVerb{tx@Dict begin /Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def end }% reset
```

So the script

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstVerb
{
    /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def %
    /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\io=1+1}{15}{%
    \pstVerb{tx@Dict begin /Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def end}% reset
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
    \multido{\ii=1+1}{\io}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)}}%
    \expandafter\psrline\points
    \psline(!CPx CPy)%
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

works fine and gives:

[image]

Comment: using `\pst@Verb` instead of `\pstVerb` has the same effect.

Comment: @CodeMocker Yes, `\pst@Verb` automatically adds the `tx@Dict begin ... end` part. But that is not obvious. And you need the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around the code, so that you don't save keystrokes. I'd prefer removing the edit and just leaving Herbert's comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Herbert's suggestion

`\pst@Verb` instead of `\pstVerb` does the scoping automatically. So it needs not to define a user dictionary.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstVerb
{
    /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def %
    /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def %
}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\io=1+1}{15}{%
    \pst@Verb{/Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def}% reset
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
    \multido{\ii=1+1}{\io}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)}}%
    \expandafter\psrline\points
    \psline(!CPx CPy)%
}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

More keystrokes have been saved!