# What is PostScript dictionary for? How to know whether or not I need it?

Tags: pstricks, postscript, pstricks-add

Consider the following code,

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstVerb
{
    /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def 
    /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def 
}

\def\WithoutDict{%
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \multido{\io=1+1}{15}
    {%
        \pstVerb{/Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def}% reset
        \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
        \multido{\ii=1+1}{\io}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)}}
        \expandafter\psrline\points
        \psline(!CPx CPy)
    }
    \end{pspicture}}

\def\WithDict{%
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \multido{\io=1+1}{15}
    {%
        \pstVerb{tx@Dict begin /Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def end}% reset
        \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
        \multido{\ii=1+1}{\io}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space updateA Angles PtoC updateCP)}}
        \expandafter\psrline\points
        \psline(!CPx CPy)
    }
    \end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\WithoutDict
\WithDict
\end{document}
```

which produces the following outputs.

[image][image]

### Question

`\WithoutDict` is different from `\WithDict` only in `tx@Dict` that `\WithoutDict` does not use. The use of `tx@Dic` in `\WithDict` was done by Christoph in [his answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156092/19356). I really don't understand why I need it.

So the question is,

1. What is PostScript dictionary for?
2. How to use it in a simple but not trivial example?
3. How do I know whether or not I need it?

Hopefully the answer can be used as a crash-course tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postscript dictionaries implement the concept of name spaces which allow for control of variable visibility. To see the command line output from the Postscript interpreter, run `ps2pdf` on the PS file produced by `dvips`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
Dictionaries implement the concept of name spaces to control variable visibility
\pstVerb{
/myvar (hello!) def % `global' definition
/mydict 1 dict def
mydict begin % open namespace
  /myvar (goodbye!) def % `local' definition
  myvar == % print local value
end % close namespace
myvar == % print global value
mydict begin % reopen name space
  myvar == % print local value once more
end
}

\end{document}
```

---

If you don't know which of the existing dictionaries from the PSTricks packages you will have to put on the dictionary stack, you can always define your variables in a new dictionary of your own. Make your dictionary the current one (and the variables defined therein available) by putting it on the dictionary stack when needed.

The dictionary and the operand stacks are separate things. Putting and popping dictionaries on the dictionary stack don't affect the operand stack:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{linecolor=red}
\pstVerb
{
    /updateCP {2 copy CPy add /CPy ED CPx add /CPx ED} bind def
    /updateA  {1 sub sqrt 1 exch atan Angles add /Angles ED} bind def
}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\multido{\io=1+1}{15}
{%
    \pstVerb{
      /mydict 1 dict def % roll your own dict
      mydict begin       % put it on top of the dict stack
        /Angles 0 def /CPx 1 def /CPy 0 def %define your variables
      end % pop your dict from the dict stack (it doesn't get lost!)
    }% reset
    \def\points{(0,0)(1,0)}% reset
    \multido{\ii=1+1}{\io}{\xdef\points{\points(!1 \ii\space
        mydict begin % make your dict the current (i.e. top-level) one by
                     %putting it on the dict stack 
          updateA Angles PtoC updateCP % work on your variables
        end % remove it from the dict stack, point coordinates remain on
            % the operand stack
    )}}
    \expandafter\psrline\points
    \psline(!mydict begin % make your dict the current dict
      CPx CPy
    end)                  % and remove it from dict stack, CPx CPy still on the operand stack
}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @CodeMocker As a PSTricks user you must care about dictionaries only if you're doing low-level stuff and you do some definitions, or if you need some special operators, which are defined in a certain dictionary. If in doubt, use the `tx@Dict` dictionary, i.e. use `\pst@Verb` instead of `\pstVerb`. But of course there is no general rule, because many packages have their own namespace dictionary (e.g. `tx@NodeDict`, `tx@FuncDict`, `tx@addDict`, `tx@EuclDict`). Some macro arguments are evaluated in one, others in another dictionary.

Comment: @CodeMocker I updated my answer, you can define variables in your own dictionary. No need to know which predefined dict to use.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, a postscript dictionary is an associative array. It can associate pairs of objects of any type, with a few exceptions. It cannot use a `nulltype` object as a key because it uses `null` to mark vacant slots in the array. It implicitly converts `stringtype` keys into `nametype`.

But it can also be used with numerical keys to implement memoized functions. It can use integer keys to represent sparse sets of character encodings, or more-generally substitution rules for string-rewriting systems. They can hold local variables for recursive functions. They can implement encapsulated objects with methods, even purely virtual ones.

Since level-2, dictionaries will automatically grow to hold their contents. This makes them very nice for implementing a growing-array, by using integer keys which work just like array indices.

```
/dictarr <<
    0 5
    1 7
    2 4
>> def
/regularr [
    5
    7
    4
] def
dictarr 1 get
regularr 1 get  % 7 7

dictarr dup length 9 put  % append to dict-array
/regularr [ regularr aload pop 9 ] def  % append to regular-array
```

To grow a regular array, you have to allocate a new one, whereas adding one more key-value pair to a dict is quite cheap since the growing of the internal array is amortized over many calls by design.

For both styles, the "index" of the last element is `length 1 sub`. Arrays, dicts, and even strings, can be used polymorphically with the `get` and `put` operators.